# Electron process.dev Configuration doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I download the source of drawio;
in `README.md`, it says

`export DRAWIO_ENV=dev if you want to develop/debug in dev mode`

I input command

`set DRAWIO_ENV=dev; npm start`

but the project still works in release mode and dev tools does not occur

How can I run it in dev mode?

Comment: `DRAWIO_ENV=dev npm start`

Answer (score 0):

`README.md` says this at #4.

`If you run in dev mode, clone https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph as a sibling directory to this repo, rename the folder containing the repo "mxgraph2".`

For example, like `/project/drawio-desktop` and `/project/mxgraph2` .

Comment: clone and rename this ```https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph``` to "mxgraph2"